# Confused on how secant slope gets simplified

Tags: calculus

I asked this question yesterday, the link is here: [Confused on secant slopes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154739/confused-on-secant-slopes/1154781#1154781)

original problem: 
$$y=-4-8x^2; P(-2,-36)$$

$$Secant Slope = \Delta y/ \Delta x = ((-4-8)-2+h^2)-(-4-8(-2)^2))/h$$

but basically I just can't for the life of me understand how it goes from a) $$ΔyΔx=[−4−8(x+Δx)^2−(−4−8x^2)Δx]=$$ to b) $$[−16xΔx−8(Δx)Δx]=−16x−8Δx.$$

How do you get -16 from $$-4-8(x+Δx)$$??? I mean, ok it makes sense that $$4^2 = 16$$ so is that how you get that? and if so, I still don't get how $$-4-8(x+Δx) $$ simplifies to $$[−16xΔx−8(Δx)2Δx] $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $(x+\Delta x)^2=x^2+2\Delta x+(\Delta x)^2$, then distribute it with the $8$.

\begin{align}
\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} &= \left[\frac{-4-8(x+\Delta x)^2 - (-4 - 8x^2)}{\Delta x}\right] \\
&= \left[\frac{-4-8[x^2+2\Delta x+(\Delta x)^2] - (-4 - 8x^2)}{\Delta x}\right]\\
&= \left[\frac{{-4-8x^2}-16\Delta x-8(\Delta x)^2 { + 4 + 8x^2}}{\Delta x}\right] \\
&= \left[\frac{-16 x \Delta x - 8 (\Delta x)^2}{\Delta x}\right] \\
&= \left[\frac{{\Delta x}(-16-8\Delta x)}{{\Delta x}}\right] \\
&=-16x - 8\Delta x \\
\end{align}

Comment: so is this just a rule then? because i also don't see how $$(x+Δx)^2=x2+2Δx+(Δx)^2$$ I obviously take your word for it but just curious because i don't really see how those equate to eachother.

Comment: @Omeed It comes from the expansion of $(a+b)^2$. Using the distributive and multiplication rule $(a+b)^2=(a+b)(a+b)=a(a+b)+b(a+b)=a^2+ab+ba+b^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$. I see on another post that you are doing calculus, i'm also doing calculus now, and other types of basic algebra is used quite frequently, it will probably help to understand basic algebra so you can focus on the calculus. 

If other things are still unclear, you can check out the following resources: https://www.khanacademy.org, https://www.youtube.com/user/TheIntegralCALC, http://patrickjmt.com, or of course MSE. Cheers. :)

Comment: I'm usually pretty good at this though which is why I am confused, but yeah thanks for the link.